# Python different mocking behaviour depending the code style

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I found a strange behavior of mocking. Could you please explain me where is the pitfall?

Searching on the net for examples for mocking i found the above piece of code, which works.

But if i rewrite it as unittest.TestCase subclass, the mocking does not works.

```
import datetime
from unittest.mock import Mock

tuesday = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
saturday = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=5)

def is_weekday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    print( "Today is %d/%d/%d"%(today.day, today.month, today.year))
    return (0 <= today.weekday() < 5)

datetime = Mock()
datetime.datetime.today.return_value = tuesday
assert is_weekday()
datetime.datetime.today.return_value = saturday
assert not is_weekday()
```

The above code will produce as expected the following

```
Today is 1/1/2019
Today is 5/1/2019
```

I rewrote the above code as subclass of unittest.TestCase

```
import unittest
import datetime
from unittest.mock import Mock

tuesday = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
saturday = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=5)

def is_weekday():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    return (0 <= today.weekday() < 5)

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        datetime = Mock()
        datetime.datetime.today.return_value = tuesday
        assert is_weekday()
        datetime.datetime.today.return_value = saturday
        assert not is_weekday()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But now the output is different

```
Today is 16/7/2021
Today is 16/7/2021
```

Comment: I wonder how your second code snippet prints anything.

Comment: You are assigning a `Mock` to a *local* variable `datetime`, not the global variable that `is_weekday` uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is lexically scoped; `is_weekday` uses a *global* name `datetime`, not the local name `datetime` you assigned the `Mock` to.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        global datetime
        old_datetime = datetime
        datetime = Mock()
        datetime.datetime.today.return_value = tuesday
        assert is_weekday()
        datetime.datetime.today.return_value = saturday
        assert not is_weekday()
        datetime = old_datetime
```

Better, though, would be to use `unittest.mock.patch`

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('datetime.datetime')
    def test_something(self, mock_dt):
        mock_dt.today.return_value = tuesday
        assert is_weekday()
        mock_dt.today.return_value = saturday
        assert not is_weekday()
```